# How to run sidekiq dashboard as a different app

Tags: sidekiq

Started GET "/jobs/dashboard/stats" gets called multiple times, when the sidekiq dashboard is running. Is there a way to run the sidekiq dashboard on a different port or as a separate application instead of the rails app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its actually ment to be run as a standalone sinatra app, rails has a facility that allows you to mount any rack compatible apps/middleware to a route which is probably what you are doing.

From the docs, in a seperate rackup file you can add

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
end

require 'sidekiq/web'
run Sidekiq::Web
```

and then just use `rackup` to start it.

See the standalone section of https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring for more options/details.